# How to compute the normal ordered angular momentum of a Klein-Gordon real scalar in terms of ladder operators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, operators, homework-and-exercises

I'm trying to compute the angular momentum
$$Q_i=-2\epsilon_{ijk}\int{d^3x}\,x^kT^{0j}\tag{1}$$
where ${T^\mu}_\nu=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}\partial_\nu\phi-{\delta^\mu}_\nu\mathcal{L}$ with the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$ on the real scalar field $\phi=\phi(x)$.

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105267/24999) is basically the same question and I'm following [the same](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html) lectures by David Tong, but the answer doesn't seem successful to me and I'm not sure if I have some mistake or if my question is ultimately about normal ordering. As stated there, the final expression of $Q_i$ in terms of ladder operators should be
$$Q_i=-i\epsilon_{ijk}\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} a^\dagger_\vec{p}\left(p_j\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}^k}-p_k\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}^j}\right) a_\vec{p}\tag{2}$$
How is this correctly calculated?

Here's what I did: As $T^{0j}=\dot\phi\partial^j\phi$ and
\begin{align}\phi=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_\vec{p}}}\left(a_\vec{p} e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}+a^\dagger_\vec{p} e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}\right)\tag{3}\\
\dot\phi=-i\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\sqrt{\frac{E_\vec{p}}{2}}\left(a_\vec{p} e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}-a^\dagger_\vec{p} e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}\right)\tag{4}\\
\partial^j\phi=-i\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{p^j}{\sqrt{2E_\vec{p}}}\left(a_\vec{p} e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}-a^\dagger_\vec{p} e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}\right)\tag{5}\end{align}
then
\begin{align}&Q_i=-2\epsilon_{ijk}\int{d^3x}\,x^k\dot\phi_p(x)\partial^j\phi_q(x)\\
&=\epsilon_{ijk}\sqrt{\frac{E_\vec{p}}{E_\vec{q}}}\int\frac{d^3pd^3qd^3x}{(2\pi)^6}x^kq^j\left(a_\vec{p}e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}-a^\dagger_\vec{p}e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}\right)\left(a_\vec{q}e^{i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{x}}-a^\dagger_\vec{q}e^{-i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{x}}\right)\\
&=\cdots\left(a_\vec{p}a_\vec{q}e^{i(\vec{p}+\vec{q})\cdot\vec{x}}+a_\vec{p}^{\dagger}a_\vec{q}^{\dagger}e^{-i(\vec{p}+\vec{q})\cdot\vec{x}}-a_\vec{p}a^\dagger_\vec{q}e^{i(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\cdot\vec{x}}-a^\dagger_\vec{p}a_\vec{q}e^{-i(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\cdot\vec{x}}\right)\tag{6}\end{align}
Now,
\begin{align}\int{d^3x}\,x^ke^{i(\vec{p}\pm\vec{q})\cdot\vec{x}}=\mp{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}^k}\int{d^3x}\,e^{i(\vec{p}\pm\vec{q})\cdot\vec{x}}=\mp{i}\,(2\pi)^3\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}^k}\delta(\vec{p}\pm\vec{q})\tag{7}\end{align}
and so
\begin{align}Q_i=-i\epsilon_{ijk}&\sqrt{\frac{E_\vec{p}}{E_\vec{q}}}\int\frac{d^3pd^3q}{(2\pi)^3}\\&q^j\left[(a_\vec{p}a_\vec{q}-a^\dagger_\vec{p}a^\dagger_\vec{q})\frac{\partial}{\partial{q}^k}\delta(\vec{p}+\vec{q})+(a_\vec{p}a^\dagger_\vec{q}-a^\dagger_\vec{p}a_\vec{q})\frac{\partial}{\partial{q}^k}\delta(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\right]\tag{8}\end{align}
Now, integrating by parts on $q$, for example, for the first term
\begin{align}\epsilon_{ijk}a_\vec{p}\int{d^3q}\,q^ja_\vec{q}\frac{\partial}{\partial{q}^k}\delta(\vec{p}+\vec{q})&=-\epsilon_{ijk}a_\vec{p}\int{d^3q}\,q^j\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial{q}^k}a_\vec{q}\right]\delta(\vec{p}+\vec{q})\\
&=\epsilon_{ijk}a_\vec{p}p^j\frac{\partial}{\partial(-p)^k}a_{-\vec{p}}\tag{9}\end{align}
and this is where I differ from the question I mentioned at the beginning. Integrating all terms in $q$,
\begin{align}Q_i=-i\epsilon_{ijk}&\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\\&p^j\left[a_\vec{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial(-p)^k}a_{-\vec{p}}-a^\dagger_\vec{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial(-p)^k}a^\dagger_{-\vec{p}}-a_\vec{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}^k}a^\dagger_\vec{p}+a^\dagger_\vec{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}^k}a_\vec{p}\right]\tag{10}\end{align}
Now, I'm guessing the first two terms vanish upon integration because they are odd in $p$, leaving
\begin{align}Q_i=-i\epsilon_{ijk}\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}p^j\left[a^\dagger_\vec{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}^k}a_\vec{p}-a_\vec{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}^k}a^\dagger_\vec{p}\right]\tag{11}\end{align}
So, if this expression is correct, how is it normal ordered?

What I tried was
\begin{align}:a^\dagger_\vec{p}(\partial_ka_\vec{p})-a_\vec{p}(\partial_ka^\dagger_\vec{p}):&=a^\dagger_\vec{p}(\partial_ka_\vec{p})-:a_\vec{p}(\partial_ka^\dagger_\vec{p}):\\
&=a^\dagger_\vec{p}(\partial_ka_\vec{p})-(\partial_ka^\dagger_\vec{p})a_\vec{p}\\
&=2a^\dagger_\vec{p}(\partial_ka_\vec{p})-\partial_k(a^\dagger_\vec{p}a_\vec{p})\tag{12}\end{align}
(where of course I'm using $\partial_k=\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}^k}$) which would yield the correct answer if $\partial_k(a^\dagger_\vec{p}a_\vec{p})=0$. I also noticed that $\partial_k(a^\dagger_\vec{p}a_\vec{p})=\partial_k(a_\vec{p}a^\dagger_\vec{p})$ since $[a_\vec{p},a^\dagger_\vec{p}]=(2\pi)^3\delta(0)$. However, I'm not really sure what's going on, whether if I made a mistake before or how to do the normal ordering if eq. (11) is right.

Answer (score 5):

Almost everything is correct except for the reasoning at step (12). It is not true that $\partial_{p_k} (a_\mathbf{p}^\dagger a_\mathbf{p}) = 0$. In case differentiating an operator with respect to momentum is unfamiliar, note that it is defined just like every other derivative,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k} \mathcal{O}(\mathbf{p}) \equiv \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\mathcal{O}(\mathbf{p} + \epsilon \hat{\mathbf{k}}) - \mathcal{O}(\mathbf{p})}{\epsilon}.$$
The operator $\mathcal{O}(\mathbf{p}) = a_{\mathbf{p}}^\dagger a_{\mathbf{p}}$ clearly depends on what $\mathbf{p}$ is, because it represents the number of particles with momentum $\mathbf{p}$. So its derivative doesn't vanish.

Instead, note that the error term is
$$\int d\mathbf{p} \, p^j \frac{\partial}{\partial p_k} (a_{\mathbf{p}}^\dagger a_{\mathbf{p}}) = \int d\mathbf{p} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial p_k} (p^j a_{\mathbf{p}}^\dagger a_{\mathbf{p}}) - \delta^{jk} a_{\mathbf{p}}^\dagger a_{\mathbf{p}}.$$
The second term vanishes by the antisymmetry of $\epsilon^{ijk}$, while the first term vanishes because it's just the integral of a total derivative. This is not any different than saying that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \, \frac{df}{dx} = 0$$
except that the letter $x$ has been replaced with $p$. You might protest that $p^j a_{\mathbf{p}}^\dagger a_{\mathbf{p}}$ does not vanish as $p \to \infty$, but as the integration bounds go to infinity, the boundary terms essentially count the number of increasingly high-energy particles, which goes to zero for any finite-energy configuration. (This is a bit mathematically cavalier, and this kind of reasoning could fail in other contexts, but it's good enough for the free scalar field.)

---

To complete the derivation very explicitly, after normal ordering we're left with
$$Q_i=-2 i\epsilon_{ijk}\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} p^j a^\dagger_\vec{p} \partial_{p_k} a_\vec{p} = -2 i\epsilon_{ijk}\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} a^\dagger_\vec{p} p^j \partial_{p_k} a_\vec{p}.$$
Since $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is antisymmetric, only the part of the integrand antisymmetric in $j$ and $k$ contributes, giving
$$Q_i= -i\epsilon_{ijk}\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} a^\dagger_\vec{p} p^j \partial_{p_k} - p^k \partial_{p_j} a_\vec{p}.$$
This is exactly what we wanted to show.

---

**Edit:** to provide even further detail we'll show how the unwanted first two terms in (10) vanish. The stated reasoning in the OP is incorrect; the terms do not just vanish by symmetry. The first term is proportional to 
$$I = \int d\mathbf{p} \, p^j a_p \frac{\partial}{\partial p_k} a_{-p}.$$
By changing variables from $p \to -p$, we find that
$$I = \int d\mathbf{p} \, (-p^j) a_{-p} \frac{\partial}{\partial (-p)_k} a_p = \int d\mathbf{p} \, p^j a_{-p} \frac{\partial}{\partial p_k} a_p = \int d\mathbf{p} \, p^j \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k} a_p\right) a_{-p}$$
since lowering operators commute. Therefore, adding these two expressions,
$$2I = \int d\mathbf{p} \, p^j \frac{\partial}{\partial p_k} (a_p a_{-p}).$$
As before, we integrate by parts. The term with $\partial p^j / \partial p_k = \delta^{jk}$ again vanishes by the antisymmetry of $\epsilon^{ijk}$. The remaining boundary term can be argued to have no contribution for finite-energy contributions, i.e. its matrix elements between any two such configurations vanishes. The same argument can be applied to the second term in (10).

Comment: Ok, that clarifies a lot. The two first terms of (10) however do not at all contain odd integrands. How to prove that they have a zero contribution?

Comment: In the reasoning used to show that what you call the 'error term' vanishes, you did not consider the factor $p^j$. It does not change the result however. One can use partial integration and the fact that $\epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial p^j}{\partial p_k}=0$ to get to the result that this term does not contribute.

Comment: @jac Thanks for the catch! I edited to address those two extra terms.

Comment: "since lowering operators commute" should be "since lowering operators and $\frac {\partial}{\partial p_k} commute. All clear to me now.

Comment: @jac No, I said that because I commuted $a_{-p}$ to the right in the last step.

Answer (score 1):

What you did seems fine to me, and indeed you can show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}^k}(a_\vec{p}^\dagger{a}_\vec{p})=0$, just take the definitions
$$a_\vec{p}=\int{d^3x}\,e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}\left[\frac{E_\vec{p}}{2}\phi(\vec{x})+\frac{i}{E_\vec{p}}\dot\phi(\vec{x})\right]\\ 
a_\vec{p}^\dagger=\int{d^3x}\,e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}\left[\frac{E_\vec{p}}{2}\phi(\vec{x})-\frac{i}{E_\vec{p}}\dot\phi(\vec{x})\right]$$ which you should be able to get from your (3) and (4) eqs, and use $\partial_x(AB)=A(\partial_x{B})+(\partial_x{A}){B}$; as the ladder operators won't get commuted, the two terms in the R.H.S. will differ by just a sign, the negative one that comes out with the annihilation operator.

Comment: You say the two will differ by just a sign, but this is not entirely true, since you get for the derivative of the planar wave something like (without the factors ~ $p_k$: 
$$i(x-y)exp(ip(x-y))*(\phi(x)\phi(y)+\dot{\phi}(x)\dot{\phi}(y)+i/2(\dot{\phi}(x)\phi(y)-\phi(x)\dot{\phi}(y)))$$ 
and for the other : 
$$exp(ip(x-y))*((p_k/4)\phi(x)\phi(y)-(p_k/(E_k^2)\dot{\phi}(x)\dot{\phi}(y))$$ and it is not obvious for me that these cancel integrating wrt $x$ and $y$.