# QFT - angular momentum operator - follow up question

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum

My question is a follow up to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142469/) question.

I've been attempting the same problem and can't figure it out.

In line 8, since $Ep$ and $Eq$ depend on $p$ and $q$ respectively, how did they move outside the $p$ and $q$ integrals?

Answer (score 0):

They shouldn't. They should stay in the integral. (but they do cancel against each other upon integrating over $p$ due to the delta functions)

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure to what degree I'm able to ask further followup questions, but when I tried to integrate by parts to take the derivatives off the delta functions, does the derivative not need to be applied to the $E_q/E_p$ term prior to applying the delta function?