# Tong QFT Problem set 2, question 6: Normal ordering of angular momentum operator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, angular-momentum

I've been studying Tong's QFT notes and am trying to do problem sheet 2, question 6. [here](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html).

We are asked to take the classical angular momentum of the field,

$\begin{align}
Q_i &= \epsilon_{ijk}\int d^3x \left(x^j T^{0k} - x^kT^{0j}\right),
\end{align}
$

and show that after normal ordering, the quantum operator $Q_i$ can be written as

$
\begin{align}
Q_i = -i \epsilon_{ijk}\int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3}a_{\vec{p}}^{\dagger}\left(p^j \frac{\partial}{\partial p_k} - p^k \frac{\partial}{\partial p_j} \right) a_{\vec{p}},
\end{align}
$

and hence to show that a stationary one-particle state has zero angular momentum.

My attempt/questions:

I use $T^{0i} = \dot{\phi}\partial^i \phi$, $\dot{\phi} = \pi$, and antisymmetry of $Q_i$ to get:

$Q_i = 2\epsilon_{ijk}\int d^3x [x^j \partial^k \phi(\vec{x})] \pi(\vec{x})$.

I then plug in the expansions for $\phi(\vec{x})$ and $\pi(\vec{x})$ and multiply it out to get that:

$Q_i = -2i \epsilon_{ijk} \int \frac{d^3xd^3p d^3q}{(2\pi)^6}\sqrt{\frac{E_{\vec{q}}}{E_{\vec{p}}}} x^j i p^k\left(a_{\vec{p}}a_{\vec{q}} e^{i(p + q)x} - a_{\vec{p}}a_{\vec{q}}^{\dagger} e^{i(p - q)x} - a_{\vec{p}}^{\dagger}a_{\vec{q}} e^{i(q - p)x} + a_{\vec{p}}^{\dagger}a_{\vec{q}}^{\dagger} e^{-i(p + q)x} \right) $,

where $x$, $p$, and $q$ are all 3-vectors, but I'm dropping the arrow.

Therefore
$Q_i = -2i \epsilon_{ijk} \int \frac{d^3p d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \sqrt{\frac{E_{\vec{q}}}{E_{\vec{p}}}} p^k \left( a_pa_q \int \frac{d^3x}{(2\pi)^3}  \frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}e^{i(p + q)x} - a_pa_q^{\dagger} \int \frac{d^3x}{(2\pi)^3}  \frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}e^{i(p - q)x} + a_p^{\dagger}a_q \int \frac{d^3x}{(2\pi)^3}  \frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}e^{i(q - p)x} - a_p^{\dagger}a_q^{\dagger} \int \frac{d^3x}{(2\pi)^3}  \frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}e^{-i(p + q)x}\right)$,

so

$Q_i = - 2 i \epsilon_{ijk}\int \frac{d^3p d^3q}{(2 \pi)^3} \sqrt{\frac{E_{\vec{q}}}{E_{\vec{p}}}}p^k \left((a_pa_q - a_p^{\dagger}a_q^{\dagger})\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}\delta(p + q) + (a_p^{\dagger}a_q - a_p a_q^{\dagger})\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}\delta(p - q) \right)$.

Invoking the product rule, I get:

$Q_i = -2i \epsilon_{ijk} \int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial p_j} \left[\sqrt{\frac{E_q}{E_p}} p^k (a_pa_q - a_p^{\dagger}a_q^{\dagger}) \delta(p + q)\right] - \frac{\partial}{\partial p_j} \left[\sqrt{\frac{E_q}{E_p}} p^k (a_pa_q - a_p^{\dagger}a_q^{\dagger})\right] \delta(p + q) +  \frac{\partial}{\partial p_j} \left[\sqrt{\frac{E_q}{E_p}} p^k (a_p^{\dagger}a_q - a_p a_q^{\dagger}) \delta(p-  q)\right] - \frac{\partial}{\partial p_j} \left[\sqrt{\frac{E_q}{E_p}} p^k (a_p^{\dagger}a_q - a_p a_q^{\dagger})\right] \delta(p - q) \right)$.
77

- If someone could walk me through the next couple of lines I would very much appreciate it. Or tell me what is wrong with what I have so far please. I can add more intermediate lines of explanation to the above if needed.

Thanks

- Relevant previous question: [QFT - angular momentum operator - follow up question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/721065/qft-angular-momentum-operator-follow-up-question)

Comment: I haven't seen your calculations, but have you tried using the product rule, i.e. $f(p)\partial_{p_j}\delta(p-q)=-[\partial_{p_j}f(p)]\delta(p-q)$??

Comment: Yes, thanks. Starting from the last line I wrote above, if I try using the product rule/integration by parts, I cannot get anything useful. It is how exactly this should play out in the next line or two that I am wondering about.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is what I get
$$\int d^3\vec{x}\ x^jT^{0k}=\int d^3\vec{x}\int 
\not{d}^3\vec{p}\int \not{d}^3\vec{p}'
\omega_p p^{'k}\Big[
a_px^je^{-i(p+p')\cdot x}a_{p'}-
a_px^je^{-i(p-p')\cdot x}a_{p'}^{\dagger}-
a_p^{\dagger}x^je^{i(p-p')\cdot x}a_{p'}+
a^{\dagger}_px^je^{i(p+p')\cdot x}a_{p'}^{\dagger}
\Big]$$
where $\not{d}^3\vec{p}=\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}$ (for short). Then, we substitute $x^j=\pm i\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}$ with the signs chosen accordingly. The result will be of the form
$$\int d^3\vec{x}\ x^jT^{0k}=\int d^3\vec{x}\int 
\not{d}^3\vec{p}\int \not{d}^3\vec{p}'
\omega_p p^{'k}\Big[
a_p i\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j} e^{-i(p+p')\cdot x}a_{p'}-
a_p i\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j} e^{-i(p-p')\cdot x}a_{p'}^{\dagger}+
a_p^{\dagger} i\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j} e^{i(p-p')\cdot x}a_{p'}-
a^{\dagger}_p i\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j} e^{i(p+p')\cdot x}a_{p'}^{\dagger}
\Big]$$
Now, recall that all the creation/annihilation operators that are located on the right of each term are functions of $\vec{p}'$ and not of $\vec{p}$! So, now we perform the product rule and subsitute $a_p\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}a_p$ and likewise for $a_p^{\dagger}$.

After performing the last step, there will be no more derivatives acting on the complex exponentials. Then, we can use the definition of the Dirac $\delta$ function and perform the integrals wrt $\vec{p}'$. The result will be
$$\int d^3\vec{x}\ x^jT^{0k}=-i\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}
p^k\Big[
\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}a_pa_{-p}-
\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}a_pa_{p}^{\dagger}+
\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}a_p^{\dagger}a_{p}-
\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}a_p^{\dagger}a_{-p}^{\dagger}
\Big]$$
$$\int d^3\vec{x}\ x^kT^{0j}=-i\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}
p^j\Big[
\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k}a_pa_{-p}-
\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k}a_pa_{p}^{\dagger}+
\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k}a_p^{\dagger}a_{p}-
\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k}a_p^{\dagger}a_{-p}^{\dagger}
\Big]$$
(or use the antisymmetry of $Q_i$ as you have nicely mentioned above, such that you don't do unnecessary calculations!) and now you can use normal ordering, as the problem suggests. Then, only one term will survive from each equation. The result will be
$$\int d^3\vec{x}\ (x^jT^{0k}-x^kT^{0j})=-i
\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}
p^k\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}a_p^{\dagger}a_{p}-
p^j\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k}a_p^{\dagger}a_{p}$$
which (upon performing the product rule once more) takes the form
$$\int d^3\vec{x}\ (x^jT^{0k}-x^kT^{0j})=i
\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}
a_p^{\dagger}\Big(p^k\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}-
p^j\frac{\partial}{\partial p_k}\Big)a_{p}$$

I hope this helps. If something is not covered properly, or if something is not clear, please comment.

**P.S.: I may have some sign errors or some other minor mistakes. I apologize in advance:)**

Comment: Thank you for this. I think you are using different sign conventions on your exponentials, but I guess that doesn't matter. I assume your $\omega_p$ is the same as my $E_p$. I don't undetstand how you are doing the integration by parts. I think by absorbing the Energy term into the measure you are acting like it isn't there. I added what I think the next line to my calculation is, perhaps it clarifies my confusion.

Comment: Yes, indeed, my $\omega_p$ is $E_p$. As far as the energy that is absorbed into the measure, I am not acting that it isn't there. It actually isn't because when you use the definition of the Dirac $\delta$ function and perform the integral wrt $\vec{p}'$, the powers of $\omega_p$ cancel! As far as the product rule is concerned, you need only keep in mind that the only functions of the momentum are the creation/annihilation operators and the momentum vectors $p^i$. Those are the ones you have to differentiate. You can verify that yourself if you want after performing the $\vec{p}'$ integral

Comment: - I'm not sure your $\omega_p$ and $\omega_{p'}$ match up with my $E_p$ and $E_q$ factors. Also, in my last line in my post, the delta functions are being applied after the differentiation, not before - so I don't see how these factors cancel.

Comment: It is just a matter of labelling... You can label the energies however you like, as long as they obey $\omega_p=\sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}$

Comment: Is there something wrong with the last line I had, after using the product rule?

Comment: The transition to the last line from the line before seems fine... You should have one integral wrt $\vec{p}$ though.

Comment: It seems to me that you are doing the right steps with the most unconvenient order... It is in your best interest to perform one of the two three-momentum integrals and then use the product rule! In this way, you will have no awkward factors of $E_p$ lying around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138263/discussion-between-gleeson-and-schris38).