# Scalar field gives spin $0$ particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

Related to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27906/angular-momentum-operator-in-terms-of-ladder-operators) question.

What needs to be shown is that the total angular momentum (derived from the Klein-Gordon lagrangian) acting on a ket with $0$ momentum, gives 0. This would mean that a scalar field theory does not give rise to intrinsic angular momentum, i.e. **spin**.

The derivation in the question above builds upon what I have already found in David Tong notes, but it all originates from quantising the classical conserved charge associated with Lorentz invariance: i.e. taking $$ \hat{\vec{J}} = -\int d^3x \, \vec{x} \times ( \hat{\pi} \,\nabla \hat{\phi})$$ where $\hat{\pi}\nabla \hat{\phi}$ is the quantised *physical* angular momentum.

Leaving aside that I am still unsure on some of the maths (see me question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155934/total-angular-momentum-in-qft)), **why do we expect spin to be included in the classically conserved (total) momentum charge**?

Comment: Flippant answer (because I've got no time right now): Spin and angular momentum are both "charges" of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ - the symmetry group doesn't distinguish among them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each relativistic field (it's not necessary for it to be the quantum one) must be lorentz-covariant object. It means that it can be represented as the direct sum of the irreducible representations of the Lorentz group. Irreducible representations of the Lorentz group are marked by two numbers $n, m$ (it means that object are transformed as n times covariant tensor and m times contravariant under the Lorentz group transformations), while sum $n + m$ refers to the eigenvalue of operator of $SU(2)$ group.

So even if you don't introduce QM, you will get the "spin" summand in Noether current which is associated with invariance of corresponding lagrangian under the Lorentz transformation of your field. After introducing QFT you'll be able to connect $n + m$ with the physical observed quantity: that eigenvalue is the eigenvalue of the generator of rotations. If you then expand your field in the direct sum of the irrep of the Lorentz group and cut off all representations except $N, M$, leaving only $2(N + M) +1$ components, you'll be able to represent the particles with a given mass and definite spin $N + M$ by this field.

But before introducing QFT the "spin" summand in Noether current doesn't have clear sense.

Comment: Is it true that any representation can be expanded as a direct sum of ir.reps?